# MongoDB Changestream Filters

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Currently using the MongoDB.Driver v2.11.0 in a .Net Core 3.1 application. Trying to read values from a changestream and have been following the documentation here:

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/driver/change_streams/

My problem is i'm trying to only get objects with a specific type and updated field, but cannot get both filters working. I can get the changestream to grab only objects that have a type of Z from the fulldocument, but cannot get any updateDescription.updatedFields filters to work properly.

Object

```
public class Abc
{
    [BsonElement("d")]
    public D D{ get; set; }
    [BsonElement("e")]
    public E E{ get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }
}

public class E
{
    [BsonElement("e")]
    public F F{ get; set; }
}

public class F
{
    [BsonElement("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

So after connecting to mongo and getting the collection here is the code to setup the change stream.

```
protected ChangeStreamOptions _changeStreamOptions => new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };

public IChangeStreamCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>> GetChangeStreamCursor()
{
    return _collection.Watch(ConfigurePipeline(), _changeStreamOptions);
}

private PipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>, ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>> ConfigurePipeline()
{
    List<IPipelineStageDefinition> pipeline = new List<IPipelineStageDefinition>();
    pipeline.Add(PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(ConfigureFilters()));
    return pipeline;
}

private FilterDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>> ConfigureFilters()
{
  var builder = Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>>.Filter;

  //here is where I build the filters and having the issues.
  //if its just based on the object type It works.

  return builder.Eq("fullDocument.d.type", "z");
}
```

This works and have no problems getting only objects that had a type of Z that were updated.
If I try to then also add a filter to only return objects of the Z and that had the field Status to have been updated to a specific type.

Here is what I've tried for that:

```
builder.Eq("fullDocument.d.type", "z") & builder.AnyEq(x => x.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields.Values, "Action");

builder.Eq("updateDescription.updatedFields.e.f.status", "Action");

builder.Eq("e.f.status", "Action");
```

The application will run with this but just never picks up any changes.

Also only tried looking at the updated fields since the UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields is an array.

```
builder.ElemMatch(x => x.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields, x => x.Name == "e.f.status" && x.Value == "Action")
```

This fails in the program main with this error

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields.'
```

Simply put I need to create a change stream and only get back objects that have a specific property type in the fulldocument and where another property was updated to a specific type.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit Update:

If I change the types to be a BsonDocument I can pass this as the pipeline and it works:

So I got it working with a BsonObject and using this:

```
var filter = "{ $and: [ { operationType: 'update' }, " +
"{ 'fullDocument.d.type' : 'z'}" +
"{ 'updateDescription.updatedFields': { 'e.f.status': 'Action' } } ] }";
```

But I would like to keep it typed if possible.

Comment: Get this working in mongo shell first, if you have difficulty remove everything .net related from the question and only leave shell commands.

Comment: Agree with the above, also regarding: `This fails in the program main with this error`, try using BsonDocument instead Abc (or any other classes). It will allow you to avoid any serialization issues, at least in the beginning

Comment: So I got it working with a BsonObject and using this:



var filter = "{ $and: [ { operationType: 'update' }, " +
"{ 'fullDocument.d.type' : 'z'}" +
"{ 'updateDescription.updatedFields': { 'e.f.status': 'Action' } } ] }";

See edit above for formatting.

Comment: see also this example https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Examples/ChangeStreamExamples.cs#L130. You should be able using your typed way instead BsonDocument in this line https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Examples/ChangeStreamExamples.cs#L156

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a solution that is working for me the way I described above.

```
private FilterDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>> ConfigureFilters()
{
    var builder = Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<Abc>>.Filter;

    var filters = builder.And(builder.Eq("fullDocument.d.type", "z") & new BsonDocument("e.f.status", new BsonDocument("$eq", "Action")));

    return filters;
}
```